# CodeIgniter session behind proxy

Tags: php, database, codeigniter, session, proxy

What happens when you don't have a list of proxy IPs? When using site acceleration services like Akamai, Google, Edgecast or CloudFront; it would always be hard to get IPs for sessions from them.

When testing our codeigniter application on a CDN, we noticed that IPs were being passed as CDN IPs and not the client IPs in the session database.

How can you get around to this?

```
    /*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Reverse Proxy IPs
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| If your server is behind a reverse proxy, you must whitelist the proxy IP
| addresses from which CodeIgniter should trust the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR
| header in order to properly identify the visitor's IP address.
| Comma-delimited, e.g. '10.0.1.200,10.0.1.201'
|
*/
$config['proxy_ips'] = '';
```

Thanks!

Comment: CDN only serves static content, doesn't it?

Comment: Well if you think about it, cloudflare recently started supporting dynamic contents so I'm thinking of future development in this area as it will be more common to server dynamic contents from CDN as well... btw cloudflare also does this.

Comment: I'm also interested on that

Comment: your CDN should be passing HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header which should have the IP of the original requester. I believe CI v2.0 or higher should already be doing this for you transparently (see session library _ip_address() method)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on the web server you use there are modules that will give you the true client IP address from the HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR header, or the equivalent for your proxy.

I use Nginx on my web server behind CloudFlare so I use this: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRealipModule

You'll need to configure the module for your web server that gets the real client IP from the correct header from your CDN.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to handle IP in Codeigniter 3 but not in the web server, you can add CDN IP into this config:

```
$config['proxy_ips'] = ['10.0.1.2'];
```

or giving a CDN network mask:

```
$config['proxy_ips'] = '10.0.1.0/24';
```

If your server is always behind CDN:

```
$config['proxy_ips'] = isset($_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]) ? $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"] : '';
```

---

#### Get IP method:

```
$this->input->ip_address(); //$this=>CI
```

It will return forward IP if matched proxy IP, otherwise it will return `$_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"]`, which could get the real client IP.

> Referring to [Codeigniter 3](https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/input.html#CI_Input::ip_address)