# CodeIgniter - Session does not always when when user is using a proxy

Tags: php, apache, codeigniter

I am current using CodeIgniter 2.2.2, and find out that when user is accessing my site via a proxy, those session variables cannot be reuse and transfer into other web pages. However, when my site is access without a proxy, all my session variables are working perfectly as it suppose to.

I am guessing the proxy somehow cuts the header or limit the session variable size or something. But I have no clue how to fix this.

Can anyone please kindly help. 
Thanks!

Comment: Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11963641/codeigniter-session-behind-proxy])

Comment: its different. what if user is using their own proxy and access my website? The session variables fails to assign to other website.

Comment: It's not my server that I am trying to bypass the proxy, I want to allow all user to use session variables regardless of whether they are accessing via proxy or not